# Server with BI application is going down daily at fixed time

Tags: server, weblogic, bi-publisher

We have a server with BI Publisher deployed on it, the server keeps hanging on daily basis at fixed time because of which even the weblogic console is not responding that time. We need to manually kill the weblogic processes and then again start nodemanager and weblogic to access console.
Can anyone help on how can I diagnose the cause for this as I'm not too good with server.

Comment: you can first check the server log to see if it is a normal stop or an unexpected stop (jvm crash for instance)

Comment: I can see outofmemory exception gc overlimit reached. Is that can be cause of issue?

Comment: yes for sure ! Logs should tell if the server is stopped due to a panic condition.